# Get elements of List

Tags: javascript, list

i have a method that returns a List<> of a custom class.
The method is called from javascript and i need to sort of parse the output of that method, has anyone got any piece of advice?

```
  $.get("/home/Method?campaign="+campaign +"&date="+date).done(function (result) {
        //code...
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse the output'? Is the response coming in a JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your intentions are. A good approach would be to return your data as a serialized JSON string. Since it looks like you're using C# (judging based on your List<> comment) perhaps look into a nice JSON serializer/deseralizer.

Once returned you can then parse that JSON back into an object and continue with where you left off.

For example,

```
$.get("/home/Method?campaign="+campaign +"&date="+date).done(function (result) {
        let data = JSON.parse(result.responseJSON.Data);
        // do stuff ...
    });
```

Comment: tyvm @MatthewHinds , i already figured it out that JSON was the best solution, but instead of parsing in js I made the method return the JSON, nevertheless thank you very much again! Have a good day!